# Startup Code in a Windows Presentation Form Application

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm working on a program that requires a file be loaded on program startup. I have seperate code for loading the file, but I've been using some basic methods to try and figure out a way to run code on the startup of a Windows Presentation Form Application. At the moment, I'm just trying to run a MsgBox function on the startup of this application. But I can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: Did you even Google this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/403418/Lifetime-events-of-a-WPF-application

Comment: Did you mean `Windows Presentation Foundation`

Answer (score 14):

From [the fine manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup.aspx):

> ## Application.Startup Event
>
> Occurs when the Run method of the Application object is called.

Example XAML:

```
<Application
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  x:Class="SDKSample.App"
  Startup="App_Startup" />
```

Example C#:

```
using System.Windows; // Application, StartupEventArgs, WindowState

namespace SDKSample
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        void App_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            // Application is running 
            // Process command line args 
            bool startMinimized = false;
            for (int i = 0; i != e.Args.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (e.Args[i] == "/StartMinimized")
                {
                    startMinimized = true;
                }
            }

            // Create main application window, starting minimized if specified
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            if (startMinimized)
            {
                mainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
            }
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```